# Issue In Lotus Notes Calendar for document created in different timezone

Tags: calendar, lotus-notes

We have a Vacation database where users create a document for vacations.  If the user is in the Central Timezone and they create a vacation document for one day, when viewing from the Calendar view, the vacation displays on the calendar for two days.

If someone in the Eastern timezone creates a vacation document for one day, this will view correctly in the Calendar view.

If the person in the Central location views the person's vacation from the Eastern time zone, the vacation displays a day earlier then the date the request was for.

If the person in the Eastern time zone views the person's vacation document from the Central time zone, the document will display in both of the days for that user even though that person  requested one day.

I know this is really screwy and we have checked the locations on the peoples systems and everything is set up correctly.
Does anyone have any ideas as to what can be the issue?

Does anyone have a vacation template from Lotus that they have used for vacation scheduling?

Thank you in advance for your comments.
Jean

Answer (score 0):

Although I can't see the details, I think your Vacation database behaves more or less correctly. The person has a vacation from day x at 00:00CST until 23:59:59. In a different time zone, this could be day x at 01:00 until day x+1 00:59:59. Or even day x at 23:00:00 until day x+1 22:59:59 !

My question: what is the purpose of the database? E.g. should it be possible to determine whether a person is available right now? I assume it works correctly in that case. Or should the HR department be able to find out how many days vacation the person took? In that case you might have a problem, which can be dealt with, no doubt about that. Also, if you don't like the way it's displayed, you can get it changed/corrected.

So, where exactly is the screwy part?